# Группировка и фильтрация по уникальному сочетанию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть таблица следующего вида:

```
user, cart
1, 1
1, 1
1, 2
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 3
2, 3
3, 1
...
```

Каким образом можно достать только те строки, где у `user` по крайне мере есть два уникальных `cart`, и только там, где `cart` с наименьшим номером. То есть, для данной таблицы я хочу получить:

```
user, cart
1, 1
1, 1
2, 1
```

`user=1` подошел, т.к. у него есть `cart=1,2`, значит мы его оставляем, но берем только `cart` с наименьшим номером, то есть 1, поэтому останутся только:

```
1, 1
1, 1
```

аналогично для `user=2`, для `user=3` не берем, т.к. там только одна уникальная `cart` равная 1.

Comment: читаю вопрос, смотрю на результат, ... перечитываю описание и ... не понимаю почему такой результат

Comment: Не знаю как это нормально описать, по сути я хочу оставить только те user у которых groupby по этому user имеет хотя бы две различные строчки, причем из этих всех различных строчек, я хочу оставить только первое сочетание, но т.к. оно может повторяться, я хочу оставить их все из исходных данных.

Comment: первое сочетание чего? у второго пользователя 3 разных `cart` - почему он отсутсвует в результате?

Comment: Он не отсутствует же, там есть 2,1 строчка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .merge(df
              .groupby("user")
              .filter(lambda x: x["cart"].nunique() > 1)
              .groupby("user")
              ["cart"]
              .min()
              .reset_index()))
```

результат:

```
In [407]: res
Out[407]: 
   user  cart
0     1     1
1     1     1
2     2     1
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)